# How to remove/disable submit on appendTo Elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've created a function to focus the next input with the enter key and disabled the submit on the form. It works fine but when I add an input field with the appendTo function it will reactivate the submit function on my form. I want to focus the input fields with the enter key and not with tab key.

Here is my function:

```
$('input').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        var index = $('input').index(this) + 1;
        $('input').eq(index).focus().val("");
        return false;
    }
});
```

And my appendTo function

```
var inputs = $('<input type="text" name="inputBasic[]" value="" class="form-control" />');
inputs.appendTo($("#dc_step_inputs"));
```

How can I remove the submit function when I add dynamical input field?
Thanks you for an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding your `keydown` event handler to a static set of elements (which does not include any elements added dynamically after your event handler has been attached), use delegation to bind to any elements that show up under your form:

```
$('#parent-form-id').on('keydown', 'input', function(e){
   if (e.which === 13) {
      var index = $('input').index(this) + 1;
      $('input').eq(index).focus().val("");
      return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('input')` only affects the elements that exist at the time this function runs.
You need to run the same script on the inserted element(s) too:

```
var inputs = $('<input type="text" name="inputBasic[]" value="" class="form-control" />');
inputs.appendTo($("#dc_step_inputs"));
inputs.keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        var index = $('input').index(this) + 1;
        $('input').eq(index).focus().val("");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can name your key down function

```
$('input').keydown(keydown);
function keydown(){
    if (e.which === 13) {
        var index = $('input').index(this) + 1;
        $('input').eq(index).focus().val("");
        return false;
    }
```

and when you create a new input, give it an id, like this:

```
var inputs = $('<input id="newInput" type="text" name="inputBasic[]" value="" class="form-control" />');
inputs.appendTo($("#dc_step_inputs"));
```

and then

```
$('#newInput').keyDown(keyDown);
```

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned, when you add an event listener to a DOM element in JavaScript, you set it again the element itself, rather than a selector, or a given collection of elements.

One way around this, is to add an event listener to a *common parent* of all the elements for which you wish your event to be triggered against. This process is called [Event Delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). Fortunately, in jQuery this is very simple, using the following syntax:

```
$(<parent_selector>).on(<event>, <child_selector>, <fn>);
```

From the example you provided this might look something like (presuming you only want to target inputs within `#dc_step_inputs`):

```
$("#dc_step_inputs").on("keydown", ":input", function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    var index = $('input').index(this) + 1;
    $('input').eq(index).focus().val("");
    e.preventDefault(); // Note, this is preferred to return False
  }
});
```